# How to extract all attribute values of <i> nested in a specific <div>

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

Im scraping a website where I have a recurring  with a varrying number of  value.

An example of one div item is like this:

```
<div class="lang">
<i class="flag fr" qtip-tooltip="Français"></i>
<i class="flag nl" qtip-tooltip="Néerlandais"></i>
<i class="flag gb" qtip-tooltip="Anglais"></i>
<i class="flag it" qtip-tooltip="Italien"></i>
</div>
```

I would like to get a `list` of all the gtip-tooltip values in a string or a list for each div. How can I do that?

I tried

```
langs = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH,value='//div[@class="lang"]')
```

but I get empty string values.

Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite close to your goal - to achieve it simply iterate over the `ResultSet` of `langs`, find all `<i>` elements for each `<div>` and extract their attributes while iterate again:

```
langs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="lang"]')
for lang in langs:
    tooltips = [l.get_attribute('qtip-tooltip') for l in lang.find_elements(By.XPATH,'.//i')]
    
    ## as list
    print(tooltips)
   
    ## as comma separated string
    print(','.join(tooltips))
```

###### Output

```
['Français', 'Néerlandais', 'Anglais', 'Italien']
```

or

```
Français,Néerlandais,Anglais,Italien
```

---

To get languages over all `div` as one `list` or better one `set` with unique values you could go with:

```
set(l.get_attribute('qtip-tooltip') for l in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="lang"]/i'))
```

Output

```
{'Anglais', 'Français', 'Italien', 'Néerlandais'}
```

Comment: Sorry that was my fault while transfer- `xpath` to select `lang.find_elements(By.XPATH,'.//i')` has to start with a `.` to avoid your described behavior. What means it has to start exactly in this `div` and not in the whole document for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.lang')
```

Then you can access your elements by loooping on your variable :

```
For element in elements :
  print(element)
```